# angularjs: refresh a module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and I am looking for advice on refreshing a module's table contents (which is a list of names and post codes in this case).

Here in script I reference the json file I want to refresh on a button press:

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http, $timeout) {
   $http.get("jsondisplay4.php")
   .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data;});

});


</script>
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
 <button ng-click="doRefresh()">Refresh</button>
<table>
<tr>
   <td>Ref</td>
   <td>Company</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>   


  <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
    <td>{{ x.Ref }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.CompanyName }}</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" ng-model="x.PostCode"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</div>
```

I currently have "doRefresh()" as the potential name, its just where to place the correct code and what it should be.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http, $timeout) {

   function run(){
    $http.get("jsondisplay4.php")
      .then(function (response) {
        $scope.names = response.data;
      });
   } 

  $scope.doRefresh = function(){
    run();
   }

   run();
});
```

When controller is loaded, it will call `run` method. `$scope.doRefresh` will do the same

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.